# XSLT transformation - adding missing siblings if not present

Tags: xslt

I am doing a transformation in XSLT. I have to add siblings if missing.

I am transforming XML given by the following XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="parent">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        ... more optional elements...
        <xs:element name="x" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="y" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="z" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:comlexType>
```

to an XML given by the following XSD

```
<xs:complexType name="parent">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        ... more optional elements...
        <xs:element name="x" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="y" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="z" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:comlexType>
```

which means that elements x and y are going from optional to required and should be added if missing. This means that my XSLT transformation should handle the following 4 cases:

**Case 1** (nothing should be added):

```
<parent>
    <a>foo</a>
    ...
    <x>foo</x>
    <y>foo</y>
    <z>foo</z>
 </parent>
```

**Case 2** (x should be added)

```
<parent>
    <a>foo</a>
    ...
    <y>foo</y>
    <z>foo</z>
 </parent>
```

**Case 3** (y should be added)

```
<parent>
    <a>foo</a>
    ...
    <x>foo</x>
    <z>foo</z>
 </parent>
```

**Case 4** (x and y should be added)

```
<parent>
    <a>foo</a>
    ...
    <z>foo</z>
 </parent>
```

I have tried the following XSLT that does not work as intended:

```
<xsl:template match="parent[not(x)]/y">
    <xsl:element name="x">foo</xsl:element>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent[not(x)]/z">
    <xsl:element name="x">foo</xsl:element>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent[not(y)]/z">
    <xsl:element name="y">foo</xsl:element>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The results for the above cases are as follows:

**Case 1** OK

```
<parent>
    <a>foo</a>
    ...
    <x>foo</x>
    <y>foo</y>
    <z>foo</z>
 </parent>
```

**Case 2** OK

```
<parent>
    <a>foo</a>
    ...
    <x>foo</x>
    <y>foo</y>
    <z>foo</z>
 </parent>
```

**Case 3** Not OK

```
<parent>
    <a>foo</a>
    ...
    <x>foo</x>
    <y>foo</y>
    <x>foo</x>
    <z>foo</z>
 </parent>
```

**Case 4** Not OK

```
<parent>
    <a>foo</a>
    ...
    <y>foo</y>
    <z>foo</z>
 </parent>
```

Comment: what does not work? How does the result differ from the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you have a `parent` element with neither an `x` nor a `y` child element, your stylesheet provides *two* equal-priority templates whose patterns match that `parent`'s `z` child.  Depending on your processor and version of XSLT, that might yield an error, but more likely results in the later-defined template being chosen.  That will get you a `y` sibling inserted, but not an `x`.

There are several ways to approach the problem.  In particular, you have a choice between using your template's pattern and using `<xsl:if>` elements to sort out the alternatives.  Here's a stylesheet that uses a bit of both to do the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="identity" match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent[not(x)]/y">
  <xsl:element name="x">foo</xsl:element>
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent[not(y)]/z">
  <xsl:if test="not(../x)">
    <xsl:element name="x">foo</xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:element name="y">foo</xsl:element>
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that did the job :)